# Esri js api 4.6 fires animation event on fast drag

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, events, animation

We are having a problem with fast drag event on the new esri js 4.6 api. When a user drags the map too fast, the map extent's changes rapidly.
I've detected that on a fast drag, there's an animation event, which is not documented. 
The [goTo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#goTo)() function also fires an animation, but it accepts duration, speed and easing as parameters.
A hacky solution is submitted as an answer, I'm still looking for a straight api approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the drag event I've changed the value of a global 'myDrag' variable to true 
`view.on('drag', function () {
    myDrag = true;
})`

This code is used to detect an active animation and to stop it if it's resulted from a drag event
(In order not to prevent all animations). 
`watchUtils.when(view, "animation", function(animation) {
     if (myDrag)
         animation.stop(); // Stops the animation.
});`

And reset the myDrag variable in the stationary state

`watchUtils.whenTrue(view, "stationary", function(e) {
  myDrag = false;
});`