# ArcGIS API 4.11 JavaScript - "Click" "drag" stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Using JavaScript in the ArcGIS API, I am querying a feature layer from a Map View, calculating points within a certain radius when the user "click" "drag" with the mouse. I want to be able to stop this functionality when the user presses the spacebar. However, I cannot get this to work. In the JavaScript I turn off event propagation for the "click" "drag" event and then cannot turn it back on again. I understand there is not a "on/off" switch for [stopPropagation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp)(). Can anyone recommend a different solution or workaround. An extract of the code I am struggling with below:

```
var bufferEnabled = false;

function keyDownListener(event) {
  var keyInput = event.key;
  bufferEnabled =
    (keyInput === " " || keyInput === "Spacebar") && !bufferEnabled;
  }

function analysis() {
view.when().then(function() {

  const layer = webmap.layers.getItemAt(0);

  view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(layerView) {
    watchUtils.whenFalseOnce(layerView, "updating", function(val) {
      // Query layer view statistics as the user clicks
      // or drags the pointer across the view.
      view.on(["click", "drag"], function(event) {
        // disables navigation by pointer drag
        event.stopPropagation();
        queryStatsOnDrag(layerView, event).then(updateCharts);
      });
    });
  });
});

    view.on("key-down", keyDownListener);
    view.on("key-down", analysis);
```

Comment: Was there any response to this one? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, my solution might help you : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270511/esri-js-api-4-6-fires-animation-event-on-fast-drag

Answer (score 1):

`view.on(...)` [returns an event object](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#on). So save a reference to that by setting a variable (`var myEvent = view.on(.....`) and then when the user indicates to toggle off, just remove the event (`myEvent.remove()`)

Comment: I don't know how to do that. You're going to have to spell it out if you will. And thank you for your reply.

Comment: If someone could elaborate on the above that would be really helpful.

Comment: Even though it's for 3.x, this [page](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_events.html) has information on removing events. You could also use [on's pausable](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_events.html) method

Comment: @kenbuja I'll take a look, thank you for that.